# Swipe Section Page - Swift 3

Tags: swift, xcode, swipe

I want to make the horizontal swipeable page like YouTube. Is there an object in XCode for this? How do I have to do it? I did not find a tutorial about it. Sorry for my English.

Like this

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by swipable page?

Comment: There is no native object like that in iOS. You should use 3rd party libraries or create your own.

Comment: Tabs like Featured, Trending and Latest.

Comment: Use a segmented control and container view to achieve such functionality. No native element available for that.

Answer (score 0):

There are tons of components already made for this in the internet, you can try looking at the cocoacontrols site.

If you still want to write your own code for this, one way is writing a custom `UIView` subclass. The YouTube feature looks very simple and as far as I can guess, they can use two separate UIView subclasses: one for the menu and one for the pages, just as a container.

For the menu you can use `UIStackView`s or a single `UIView`s with `UIButton`s for the page's titles and another view for the selection effect that moves with the `UIButton`'s touch event. This view should provide a delegate or any notification system that fits better to you in order to notify the container that needs to load the right `UIViewController`'s view inside the container.

The container can be a UIView that loads the view property from the UIViewController subclass on demand. Make sure to add the loaded view controller as a child of the parent view controller, otherwise you will loose some important features.

I hope it can help you to start.